# Add category attribute with WYSIWYG enabled

Tags: magento, wysiwyg, categories, custom-attributes

I'm following this tutorial: http://www.atwix.com/magento/add-category-attribute/
All is working well, attributes are added to categories, but without the WYSIWYG button below the field. WYSIWYG is enabled in System > Config > Content Management.

```
$this->startSetup();
$this->addAttribute('catalog_category', 'custom_att', array(
    'group'         => 'General',
    'input'         => 'textarea',
    'type'          => 'text',
    'label'         => 'My attribute',
    'backend'       => '',
    'visible'       => true,
    'required'      => false,
    'wysiwyg_enabled' => true,
    'visible_on_front' => true,
    'is_html_allowed_on_front' => true,
    'global'        => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
));
$this->endSetup();
```

Whatever I try, WYSIWYG is not enabled for my attributes. Can anyone help? Or maybe there is a workaround for this?

EDIT: I searched other posts but all say that this code should add the WYSIWYG:

```
'wysiwyg_enabled' => true,
```

but it doesn't.

Comment: Make sure that `$this` is an instance of `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Setup`, not `Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup`.

Answer (score 12):

Tried to accomplish same task today and searching through magento code managed to complete my task with this code:

```
$productEntityTypeId = $installer->getEntityTypeId('catalog_product');
$installer->addAttribute($productEntityTypeId, 'some_text', array(
    'group'         => 'General',
    'input'         => 'textarea',
    'type'          => 'text',
    'label'         => 'Some Text',
    'backend'       => '',
    'visible'       => true,
    'required'      => false,
    'visible_on_front' => true,
    'global'        => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
));
$installer->updateAttribute($productEntityTypeId, 'some_text', 'is_wysiwyg_enabled', 1);
$installer->updateAttribute($productEntityTypeId, 'some_text', 'is_html_allowed_on_front', 1);
```

Answer (score 7):

This works:

```
$installer->updateAttribute('catalog_category', 'certifications', 'is_wysiwyg_enabled', 1);
$installer->updateAttribute('catalog_category', 'certifications', 'is_html_allowed_on_front', 1);
```

Comment: Can you provide a little more support for your answer? Why does it work?

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me:

```
$installer->addAttribute('catalog_category', 'short_description', array(
    'type' => 'varchar',
    'label' => 'Short Description',
    'input' => 'textarea',
    'default' => '',
    'sort_order' => 1,
    'required' => false,
    'wysiwyg_enabled' => true,
    'visible_on_front' => true,
    'is_html_allowed_on_front' => true,
    'global' => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_STORE,
    'group' => 'General Information',
));
```

Notice the following three entries:

```
    'wysiwyg_enabled' => true,
    'visible_on_front' => true,
    'is_html_allowed_on_front' => true,
```

Using Magento CE 1.9.2.0.

Comment: This worked for me, but I found `'type' => 'text'` was more useful to me because varchar has a 255 character limit.

Comment: I had to use ```is_wysiwyg_enabled``` for this to work

Answer (score 1):

Create php file in magento root directory and paste below code and run it from browser:-

```
ini_set('display_errors',0);
require_once 'app/Mage.php';
Mage::app();

$setup = new Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup('core_setup');


function createNewAttributeSet($name) {
    Mage::app('default');
    $modelSet = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute_set')
    ->setEntityTypeId(4) // 4 == "catalog/product"
    ->setAttributeSetName($name);
    $modelSet->save();
    $modelSet->initFromSkeleton(4)->save(); // same thing
}

// Replace your attribute name with "extra_info"

$setup->addAttribute('catalog_category', 'extra_info', array(
        'group'             => 'General Information',
        'type'              => 'text',
        'backend'           => '',
        'frontend'          => '',
        'label'             => 'Extra Information',
        'wysiwyg_enabled' => true,
        'visible_on_front' => true,
        'is_html_allowed_on_front' => true,
        'input'             => 'textarea',
        'class'             => '',
        'source'            => 'eav/entity_attribute_source_boolean',
        'global'     => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_STORE,
        'visible'           => 1,
        'required'          => 0,
        'user_defined'      => 0,
        'default'           => '',
        'searchable'        => 0,
        'filterable'        => 0,
        'comparable'        => 0,
        'visible_on_front'  => 0,
        'unique'            => 0,
        'position'          => 1,
));
$setup->updateAttribute('catalog_category', 'extra_info', 'is_wysiwyg_enabled', 1);
$setup->updateAttribute('catalog_category', 'extra_info', 'is_html_allowed_on_front', 1);
```

Comment: You are welome :)